# string to \xHH in PHP

Tags: php, xss, encode, owasp, websecurity

I am curious is that any build in or easier way to encode string to \xHH format in PHP? I am trying to implement rule 3 and rule 4 from [XSS OWASP Prevention](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross_Site_Scripting_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html#rule-3-javascript-encode-before-inserting-untrusted-data-into-javascript-data-values) with build in function or easier approach. but, I can't find any in the internet.

as far as I found, I need to make manual encoder/decoder for 'string to \xHH' format in PHP.

*expected code in php*

```
print(StringToXHH("foo"));
// output --> \x66\x6f\x6f
```

any idea?

Comment: Dont you mean `\x66\x6f\x6f`.

Comment: You can encode JavaScript literals with `json_encode()` if that's what you mean.

Comment: bin2hex("f") \\ 66

Comment: Abra -> edited.
Alvaro -> solved. thanks
Eden -> read the question again. but thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the answer in this SO question [How do I pass variables and data from PHP to JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740548/how-do-i-pass-variables-and-data-from-php-to-javascript), specifically the section ***3. Echo the data directly to JavaScript***.

It isn't exactly the answer to your question, but addresses the overall issue.

*tldr: use `json_encode()`*.